# JSON SWIFT 3 Parsing to s single string Yahoo API

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to use a Yahoo API to load some stocks but can't do it, please help

```
func getJSon() {
    stockCode = self.stockCodeTextfield.text!
    urlString = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes.csv%3Fs%3D" + stockCode + "%26f%3Dsl1d1t1c1ohgv%26e%3D.csv'%20and%20columns%3D'symbol%2Cprice%2Cdate%2Ctime%2Cchange%2Ccol1%2Chigh%2Clow%2Ccol2'&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let data = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)
    let values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
```

until this 
point loads the Json to xcode I think I need to access some keys I'm lost

```
let maindata = values[0]
let price = maindata["price"]
print(price)
```

> > {"query":{"count":1,"created":"2017-05-04T22:24:25Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"row":{"symbol":"TERP","price":"12.30","date":"5/4/2017","time":"4:00pm","change":"-0.12","col1":"12.41","high":"12.51","low":"12.28","col2":"366182"}}}}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is very unclear and vague, but if you are asking how to get to the "results" section of your JSON the simple answer is that you'd do this:

```
if let query = values["query"] as? [String : Any], let results = query["results"] as? [String : Any], let row = results["row"] as? [String : Any] {
    //Now you're inside the "results" dictionary
}
```

If you need to print the "price" from within "results" you'd do this:

```
if let query = values["query"] as? [String : Any], let results = query["results"] as? [String : Any], let row = results["row"] as? [String : Any] {
    if let row = results["row"] as? [String : Any], let price = row["price"] as? String {
        print(price)
    }
}
```